# Linq to entity left join

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I can't get the right result, maybe it broke at the first query, can someone find the problem.

```
var query = from case in dbEntity.Cases
    join Comm in dbEntity.Comms on case.log_id equals comm.CaseId into collection
    from subCase in collection.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { case, subCase.status };
```

I want to get all the Cases and the status value in `Comms`. `log_id` and `CaseId` are the join keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from case in dbEntity.Cases
join Comm in dbEntity.Comms on case.log_id equals comm.CaseId into collection
from subCase in collection.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { Case=case,Status= (subCase==null?null:subcase.Status };
```

Comment: I want to ask additional question, if I want to use Case in .Where() function, should I use the form like"c.Case.property"?

Comment: if you want to apply where in above join then just write where case.Property>10 (say) before select clause